# Apply function in UNIQUE constraint in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, unique-constraint

I would like to add a multi column unique constraint to my MySQL 5.7 database table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE report_summary 
ADD UNIQUE (
    tenant_id, 
    app_id, 
    date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d')
);
```

...but it gives me the following error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d'))' at line 1`

I want to add a constraint that one day only have one line for one app per tenant, so what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Create generated column which uses built-in function, and use it in your index.

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME is dependent on the timezone of the current session and therefore can't be used. I'm working to get this fixed in mariadb (MDEV-21593).  A simpler expression like `statistic_time DIV (1000 * {seconds in day})` may be a start (or possible in a generated column)